# How can I privately deploy a React Native (expo) app?

Tags: android, react-native, deployment, expo

I apologize if it sounds like a silly question, but this is my first time with React Native and I would like to have some information regarding the deployment.

I'm developing a small Android app for a goliardic birthday joke. Basically, the app makes use of the geolocation for a treasure hunt within my country.

For obvious reasons I cannot publish such an app on the Google Play Store.

Is there an alternative private distribution path that allows me to download and run the application exclusively on the mobile phone of the person concerned?

Thanks so much

Comment: You can build the `apk` using `expo build` or `eas build` and get it from  [Expo Dashboard](https://expo.dev/E)

Comment: Thank you so much!